# PHP REGEX single quote and white spaces

Tags: php, regex, match

Hi I'm new to REGEX and want to be able to find a string with any character, white spaces, or a single quote in it. This is what I have:

```
    preg_match('/title="([A-Za-z\'\w]+)"/', 'title="Some ' text"', $match);
    echo $match[1];
```

I want this to output:

```
    Some ' text
```

Comment: So you want a regular expression to select any string what so ever or did you mean you want only a string that starts with any character followed by a white space and a single quote?

Comment: By 'any character', you mean 'any letter'? Character is like... "everything" from letters, digits, to all sorts of symbols. If you really mean letter, then you shouldn't use `\w`, since this accepts digits as well, and underscores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape quote inside string.

And add **\s** to your regexp, to match all whitespaces

Also **\w** covers **a-zA-Z**

```
 preg_match('/title="([\'\w\s]+)"/', 'title="Some \' text"', $match);
 echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, just tested it.

```
$match = array(); 
$text = "title=\"Some ' text\""; 
preg_match("/[a-z]*\s\'\s[a-z]*/i", $text, $match);
echo print_r($match);
```

It will out put

```
Array ( [0] => Some ' text ) 1
```